# Mail merge in Microsoft Word: Making blank lines disappear if the field they are attached to is blank

Tags: microsoft-word

I am creating a mail merge document to inform family members that one or more donors gave a donation in memory of their loved one. At the bottom are some fields that I am mail merging in from Raiser's Edge.

What I want to do is make it so that if there is no second donor, not only does the "«AddresseeSalutation_2_Donor_Addressee»" part not appear (that is already true), but I also want the blank line *above that* (the line between «Address_1_Donor_Address_Block» and «AddresseeSalutation_2_Donor_Addressee») to also not appear.

There's actually room for 10 donors in the mail merge document and I don't want to have to delete anywhere up to 9 extra blank lines in every letter that doesn't have 10 donors.

```
«AddresseeSalutation_1_Donor_Addressee»
«Address_1_Donor_Address_Block»

«AddresseeSalutation_2_Donor_Addressee»
«Address_2_Donor_Address_Block»

«AddresseeSalutation_3_Donor_Addressee»
«Address_3_Donor_Address_Block»
```

---

```
«AddresseeSalutation_1_Donor_Addressee»
«Address_1_Donor_Address_Block»
                 <-- This is the line I want to remove if there's nothing below it.
«AddresseeSalutation_2_Donor_Addressee»
«Address_2_Donor_Address_Block»
```

Many thanks for the help!